# c++ g++ & boost, missing binary operator before token "("

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, g++

The line of code g++ is complaining about is:

```
#if BOOST_WORKAROUND(__MWERKS__, BOOST_TESTED_AT(0x3205))
```

I don't understand why it is complaining about a binary operator here, is this a g++ or boost bug?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the complete error messages?

Comment: "is this a g++ or boost bug?" Most probably: no.

Comment: I am not sure, but identifier `__MWERKS__` suggests that this particular line is for Metrowerks CodeWarrior compiler, not for GCC. And AFAIR Metrowerks might have expanded C macros differently (I dont want to say incorrectly, but... _strange_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get that error if `BOOST_WORKAROUND` is not defined, so I'm guessing you're using the macro without actually including any Boost headers.  Which won't work, obviously.

It's usually safest to assume it's *not* a bug in one on of the most widely-used compilers and most widely-used libraries in the world, and you're just doing something wrong.